# Function not being called

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to test some jQuery in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjsfiddlenetuser/WhKqZ/):

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<input name="Button3" type="button" value="Invoke" onclick="get()">
```

```js
function get() {
    var data = {};
    data.foo = "bar";
    data.stuff = {
        nifty: "stuff"
    };

    $("#myDiv").text(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

The `get()` function is not being called when I press 'Invoke'. What should occur is the `div` content should get updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your fiddle doesn't work is because the settings are wrong. Change `onLoad` inthe dropdown on the left to `no wrap (head)` and it will work.

However, as you're using jQuery for your logic, it's best practice to use it to attach events too rather than use the clunky `onclick` attributes. Try this:

```
<input name="Button3" type="button" value="Invoke" id="button">
```

```js
$("#button").click(get);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WhKqZ/1/)

Comment: @PriyankPatel Because the jsfiddle settings were wrong. Change `onLoad` on the left, to `no wrap (head)` and it will work.

Comment: i think he asked: why the function not being called ?

Comment: Yeah he did, and I explained why. Read the first paragraph of my answer. Then please remove your downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Jsfiddle evaluates your function on windows.load event:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
function doSomething() {
    var data = {};
    data.foo = "bar";
    data.stuff = {nifty: "stuff"};

    ("#myDiv").text(JSON.stringify(data));
}

});//]]>  

</script>
```

but the browser needs it on header or before than element that references to it.

you must to chage your code to this:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function doSomething() {
    var data = {};
    data.foo = "bar";
    data.stuff = {nifty: "stuff"};

    $("#myDiv").text(JSON.stringify(data));
}
</script>

<input name="Button3" type="button" value="Invoke" onclick="doSomething()">
​
```

BUT,

its recommended to use jquery style event attachment:

```
<input id="myBTN" name="Button3" type="button" value="Invoke" />
$('#myBTN').click(function(e){
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go the updated [jiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WhKqZ/7/)

you are calling the function using javascript whereas you have declared the function in you jQuery library.

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<input name="Button3" type="button" value="Invoke">
```

**Script inside document ready**

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function () {
get();
})

function get() {
var data = {};
data.foo = "bar";
data.stuff = {nifty: "stuff"};

$("#myDiv").text(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa - thank very much for your advise but please give atleast 1 min to us to edit our answer..

Comment: @Murtaza , why are you referring to yourself in plural ?

Comment: I do my friend it has nothing to do with rep. answering here is important and i did that very well. you can see in my answer. What ever you are doing here my posting comments is unnecessary. if you have problem in my answer please let me know.

Comment: "if you have problem in my answer please let me know." That's what I did. By downvoting and I was so nice to post a comment about why I downvoted. Once the issue was fixed I removed downvote. Don't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: ya thats write but it did not liked you posted on my rep. it is hard points earned by answering.. i did not liked u mentioned my rep. for no reason well you downvoted with 30 secs should have waited for 1 min to see if i am updating

Comment: Rep has anything to do with it. Rep is a way of showing how much you are trusted by the community. What I think you did was trying to be [TFGITW](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite-on-mso). And saying that your question was very well [is wrong](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Last thing I'm gonna say about it: get over it